How to run two applications redirecting through DNS
I tried nginx
but it always opens the application on port 81 in both applications

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.1.1.19:81;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  monitoresuvv;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.1.1.19:82;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I configured nginx in the conf file and ran it using start nginx if anyone can help
Note if I change the application ports it always runs at 81, both are reacts applications and I use express in the backend running on other ports that do not need to be in nginx
